# Why this next_page_link can't work correctly?

Tags: php, if-statement, hyperlink, vbulletin

I have a code that basically is a "previous page" and "next page" button. The problem is that 'previous_page' works correctly but 'next_page' not  and I don't know why.

Someone see something wrong in this code?

```
if ($vbulletin->GPC['pagenumber'] > 1) {
    k_add_function(
        $vbphrase['k_showthread_previous_page']
        ,$vbulletin->options['k_previous_page']
        ,"showthread.php?t={$threadinfo['threadid']}&amp;page=" . ($vbulletin->GPC['pagenumber']-1)
        ,$vbphrase['k_showthread']
    );
} else if ($vbulletin->GPC['pagenumber'] < ceil($totalposts / $perpage)) {
    k_add_function(
        $vbphrase['k_showthread_next_page']
        ,$vbulletin->options['k_next_page']
        ,"showthread.php?t={$threadinfo['threadid']}&amp;page=" . ($vbulletin->GPC['pagenumber']+1)
        ,$vbphrase['k_showthread']
    );
}
```

I was wondering if maybe could be related with my modrewrite url-path which is `[forum_title]/index[forum_page].html` but the true is that previous_page works so I don't know... I would appreciate some help.

Comment: If you type in the address for showthread.php directly into the url with any valid page number does it work? i.e if you manually go to the page instead of using the link does it work?

Comment: Yes, if I access manually to [showthread.php?t=ID&page5] I get redirected to the correct page.

Comment: OK, great, so now if you inspect the html generated does the next page link have the correct url exactly the same as you manually typed it?

Comment: I can't see the html generated because in reality this is a keyshort for keyboard (a = previous page and s = next page) but  I suspect that generate showthread.php?id=X&page=X . a=Previous works great but s=Next only works one time (until page 2), if I press again "S" to  go page3... nothing happens)

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen a potential typo, could this be the problem:

In the prev link you have `$vbphrase['kb_showthread']` but in the next link you have `$vbphrase['k_showthread']` should the next link also be `$vbphrase['kb_showthread']`